# In Android how to pass HTTP streaming video URL from my app to other app which is streaming player?

Tags: android, video, android-intent, streaming

I would like to take the HTTP URL streaming video from my app to other app which is streaming player and play the streaming and when I come out from that another app it should directly back to my app.

thanks in advance

Best rgds
singha

Answer (score 0):

You can just start an activity of that streaming app and pass a bundle to that activity with all required information about streaming, like HTTP URL

Here is the syntax you have to use to start that activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.MyExampleActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like...

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://server.yourcompany.com:1234/video.3gp";
i.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
try {
    startActivity(i);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Handle exception
} catch (Exception e) {
    Handle exception
}
```

The above code will attempt to start the default video player app on the device. The user will have to press the `Back` button after the video finishes to get back to your app though.

Comment: I have an youtube rtsp url, same i am trying to play like you playing for http, but it's not working..have any idea/suggestion?